# Complicated ORDER BY needed to sort irregular values

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to develop a system to display products from a database on a webpage. Normally this is no problem, except that one manufacturer has several abnormal part numbers I need to sort by properly.

Normally, I could just use an invisible column to sort things out, but then that makes inserting new items in-between two older ones much more difficult.

For example, here are some of the part numbers:

```
1211
1225
14-302
14-303
2015
23157
3507
35280UP
42-3309
42-3312
4241
```

Now, the normal order by mfgr produces the above order.
What it SHOULD be is something more like this:

```
14-302
14-303
42-3309
42-3312
1211
1225
2015
3507
4241
23157
35280UP
```

What is going to be my best bet on sorting this properly? If they were just being made in a csv file and uploaded afterwards this wouldn't be a problem. But because of automatic database changes, the server will be modifying values in real time. So manually updating it is out of the question. This means that a back end will be required to insert new items, but by what method could I insert an item between another? I would prefer to not resort to something like decimals to give me X in between values (Like I have 1.00 and 2.00 and I want to put another between them so I make it 1.50).

Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT:**

The way I would like to sort it is this:
if it has a hyphen, ie 14-302, it is sorted by the 14, and then any 14-xxx is sorted by the numbers after the hyphen.
then, just numbers would be sorted by their actual numner, 802 comes before 45768.
Then any number that has a letter(s) after it will be sorted by the number, the the letter so 123a comes before 123b but after 122. And 123b comes before 124c.
and lastly anything that begins with an M- will be sorted last, and by the numbers after the hyphen.

Comment: Step 1: Define the rule that decides the ordering.

Comment: I thought I kind of had but ill do a better job in an edit.

Comment: It seems like a situation in which you could use mysql REGEXP. Here is a startup for you: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ffd2ce/7 You can learn more about the usage here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/regexp.html

Comment: regexp might be the way to go, but that particular setup doesn't work right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your adjusted question the principle is still the same.
My first instinct was to go with extra field but you could use stored function for those.
You still need to divide your partnumber in 3 parts (I take it it's not more than that).

- Part1 is an INTEGER and has the first number if existing else fill it with maxint (largest for part1).
- Part2 is a CHAR and contains letters if existing.
- Part3 is an INTEGER containing the second number if existing.

You can sort by calling a function for these values.

Here is the complete source:
For your convenience a link to a working [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6df18/1/0).
It's really sloppy/fast programming but it works. Put together in little time and i'm sure there are points for improvement. You can tweak it yourself. Later you can delete the part1, part2 and part3 from the view. (but leave it in the `order by`) It's only to show how the sort is done.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `uGetParts`//
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `uExtractPart1`//
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `uExtractPart2`//
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `uExtractPart3`//

CREATE PROCEDURE `uGetParts`(
  IN ins varchar(50),
  OUT num1 int unsigned,
  OUT num2 int unsigned,
  OUT num3 int unsigned)
NO SQL
BEGIN
  SET num1=0;
  SET num2=0;
  SET num3=0;
  WHILE (num1<length(ins)) AND
    (SUBSTRING(ins,num1+1,1) REGEXP('(^[0-9]+$)')=1) DO
      SET num1=num1+1;
  END WHILE;
  SET num2=num1;
  WHILE (num2<length(ins)) AND
    (SUBSTRING(ins,num2+1,1) REGEXP('(^[0-9]+$)')=0) DO
      SET num2=num2+1;
  END WHILE;
  SET num3=num2;
  WHILE (num3<length(ins)) AND
    (SUBSTRING(ins,num3+1,1) REGEXP('(^[0-9]+$)')=1) DO
      SET num3=num3+1;
  END WHILE;
END//

CREATE FUNCTION `uExtractPart1`(ins varchar(50))
RETURNS int unsigned NO SQL
BEGIN
  DECLARE num1 INT default 0;
  DECLARE num2 INT default 0;
  DECLARE num3 INT default 0;
  call uGetParts(ins,num1,num2,num3);
  IF num1>0 THEN       
    RETURN CAST(SUBSTRING(ins,1,num1) AS UNSIGNED);
  ELSE
    RETURN ~0 >> 32;
  END IF;  
END//

CREATE FUNCTION `uExtractPart2`(ins varchar(50))
RETURNS varchar(50) NO SQL
BEGIN
  DECLARE num1 INT default 0;
  DECLARE num2 INT default 0;
  DECLARE num3 INT default 0;
  call uGetParts(ins,num1,num2,num3);
  IF num2>num1 THEN       
    RETURN SUBSTRING(ins,num1+1,num2-num1);
  ELSE
    RETURN '';
  END IF;  
END//      

CREATE FUNCTION `uExtractPart3`(ins varchar(50))
RETURNS int unsigned NO SQL
BEGIN
  DECLARE num1 INT default 0;
  DECLARE num2 INT default 0;
  DECLARE num3 INT default 0;
  call uGetParts(ins,num1,num2,num3);
  IF num3>num2 THEN       
    RETURN CAST(SUBSTRING(ins,num2+1,num3-num2) AS UNSIGNED);
  ELSE
    RETURN 0;
  END IF;  
END//
```

You can call it like this:

```
SELECT 
  id,
  TYPE,
  uExtractPart1(TYPE) as part1,
  uExtractPart2(TYPE) as part2,
  uExtractPart3(TYPE) as part3
FROM Article
ORDER BY 
  uExtractPart1(TYPE),
  uExtractPart2(TYPE),
  uExtractPart3(TYPE)
```

Comment: breaking the the number into 3 fields is a possibility but would be annoying. Why can't I use REGEXP?

Comment: That depends. You said it doesn't "work right" in your setup. What did you mean by that? (the sorting was exactly as you stated in your original question)

Comment: The sorting does not put it how I stated in my original question. The sorting puts out 1211, 3507, 23157, 2015, 1225, etc. That is not right in the slightest. It should be 1211, 1225, 2015, 3507, 23157.

Comment: I revised my answer. Now with a function call per part. (including working [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6df18/1/0))

Comment: That's great! But a little complicated for me to replicate, as I have some other (less obscure) numbers to sort, such as 87-10-2, 87-1000, etc. Is REGEXP another option? If I can't get anything else as good as this I'll just use it.

Comment: The problem with REGEXP is that it's only for matching a string. It gives a 1 for true and 0 for false. There is no simple way to EXTRACT a string with a regexpression. You could look in udf-function but they will not be simpeler than this. You could extend my example to include those other numbers. Like Ignacio said... you need to define all your rules. All your possible variation in numbers and build from there. (For your extra given numbers you could ignore the hyphen. But you need to decide where that '10' goes. Before or after the letters... etc...)

Comment: Would be handy to know what syntax error? On SQL Fiddle it worked. b.t.w. i used DELIMITER //. (See the pulldown below the schema. SQL Fiddle does not accept DELIMITER as keyword so you have to change the // or add `delimiter //` in your database.

Comment: If the delimiter is the problem. You can set `delimiter //` in front of the definitions and back to `delimiter ;` after.

Comment: I changed the delimiter to //, I'm using phpmyadmin.

This is the error:
There seems to be an error in your SQL query. The MySQL server error output below, if there is any, may also help you in diagnosing the problem

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE len INTEGER default 0;
  SET num1=0;
  SET num2=0;
  SET num3=0;
  W' at line 2

Comment: phpmyadmin also doesn't know the `delimiter` keyword. However... below the SQL-box (in the second tab "SQL") there is a box for the delimiter character. set that to //. Default it says ;.

Comment: I take it you used exact same code? Could you paste your code back to sqlfiddle to see if it works there. (And give link if not.) I used the exact same code in my phpmyadmin and it worked.

Comment: All I did is copy paste what you put in the first code block (starting with create procedure and ending with end//) and change the delimiter to // instead of ;. I get the error. I paste it into sqlfiddle and get no errors.

Comment: What version of mysql and phpmyadmin do you have?

Comment: Changed the code again. I used INTEGER and INT both. Here it just works but perhaps INTEGER is a problem with an older MySql/phpmyadmin. Updated code is in answer and [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/83884/1/0)

Comment: My phpymyadmin says version: 5.0.96 under global variables.

When I try to run the query I get this error now:
You do not have the SUPER privilege and binary logging is enabled (you *might* want to use the less safe log_bin_trust_function_creators variable)

Comment: Then you've got a privilege problem. You can read about your error [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_super). You need either SUPER privilege or create these procedures as a user who has these privileges. I googled it and you could use 'SET GLOBAL log_bin_trust_function_creators = 1//' but you need to read up on this setting to check what it does and what de consequences are of setting it to 1.

Comment: I'm not sure my host will allow me to do that. I'll look into it, thanks for all the help!

Comment: They should give you the ability to set log_bin_trust_function_creators or SUPER user access. Or else you'll never be able to create a procedure (what seems silly to me) [see here](http://serverfault.com/questions/55752/mysql-super-privilege-vs-log-bin-trust-function-creators). Good luck.